# Help with uploading file with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a form that I am trying to upload a file to the server with and then save the info to the database. Saving the info to the database works fine except for the file information and the file doesn't upload. My code is below. Any help is appreciated.

**Form**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="editeventform" class="editeventform" enctype="multipart/form-data">       
        <input type="hidden" name="eventid" id="eventid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <table class="editeventtable">
            <tr>
                <th align="right" valign="top">Title:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="right" valign="top">Date:</th>
                <td><input type="date" name="newdate" id="newdate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="<?php echo $newdate; ?>" /> <i><b>Format as mm/dd/yyyy</b></i></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="right" valign="top">Time:</th>
                <td><input type="time" name="newtime" id="newtime" placeholder="hh:mm am/pm" value="<?php echo $newtime; ?>" /> <i><b>Format as hh:mm am or pm</b></i></td>
            </tr>
            <?php if (isset($file)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th align="right" valign="top">Delete File:</th>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkdel" value="yes"> <i><b>Leave unchecked if uploading a new file. File will be replaced with the new one.</b></i></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <tr>
                <th align="right" valign="top">Upload New File:</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="infofile" id="infofile" accept=".pdf"> <i><b>This will overwrite any file already uploaded.</b></i>
                    <?php if (isset($file)) { ?><input type="hidden" name="oldfile" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" /><?php } ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="right" valign="top">Information:</th>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    //$content = $info;
                    $editor_id = 'info';
                    $settings = array(
                        'textarea_name' => 'info',
                        'editor_height' => 425,
                        'media_buttons' => FALSE,
                        'tinymce' => array(
                            'width' => 1000,
                        )
                    );
                    wp_editor( $info, $editor_id, $settings );
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <button>Save Edit</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="editeventform">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.editeventform').submit(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var editeventform = $('.editeventform');
            $.ajax({
                url: editeventform.attr('action'),
                data: editeventform.serialize(), // form data
                type: editeventform.attr('method'), // POST
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#response').html(data); // Display Results
                }
            });
            return false;
        }); 
    });
```

**PHP**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_editeventform', 'save_edit_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_editeventform', 'save_edit_form');
function save_edit_form() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $wp_filesystem_direct;

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $id = $_POST["eventid"];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $date = $_POST['newdate'];
    $newdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
    $time = $_POST['newtime'];
    $newtime = date("G:i", strtotime($time));
    $info = wpautop($_POST['info']);

    if (!empty($_FILES['infofile']['name'])) {
        if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        }
            
        $filename = $_FILES['infofile']['name'];

        $table = $wpdb->prefix . "events";
        $data = array(
            'title' => $title,
            'date' => $newdate,
            'time' => $newtime,
            'info' => $info,
            'filename' => $filename,
        );
        $where = array(
            'id' => $id
        );
        $wpdb->update($table, $data, $where);
            
        $dirfile = wp_upload_dir();
        $dirname = $dirfile['basedir'] . '/communitybb_events/files/' . $id . '/';
            
        wp_mkdir_p($dirname);
            
        $source = $_FILES['infofile']['tmp_name'];
        $destination = $dirname . $_FILES['infofile']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($source, $destination);              
    } else {
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . "events";
        $data = array(
            'title' => $title,
            'date' => $newdate,
            'time' => $newtime,
            'info' => $info,
        );
        $where = array(
            'id' => $id
        );
        $wpdb->update($table, $data, $where);
    }
    ?>
    <h3><?php echo $title; ?> Has Been Updated</h3>

    <?php

    die;
}
```